# passing <a> value to next page which all the href are same page that will process the data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am a new to programming. I like to ask that how can I retrieve the value of the `<a>` or text

that is hyperlinked and post it to the next page(`abc.php`). All of the hyperlinked `$row['a']` will go to abc.php and process the data based

on the hyperlinked `$row['a']` that is clicked. For now, I keep getting undefined, `<a>` contains

nothing?!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        alert("As you can see, the link no longer took you to jquery.com");
        var a = $(this).attr('a');
        alert(a);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>  

echo "<td>"."<a href='abc.php'>".$row['a']."</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the content of `a` element you need to use `$(this).text()` as @Rodion suggested.

The next step will be to send that data through to abc.php by the use of query string: `abc.php?ref=[...]`.

Consider the following Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(event) {

        var text = $(this).text();

        alert("As you can see, the link no longer took you to jquery.com");
        alert(text);

        window.location.href = window.location.href + '?ref=' + text;

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

It retrieves the text of the `a` element from the Document Object Model and then adds it to the query string of the location referenced by the link.

The last thing to do in here is to prevent the browser from instantly following the reference in `href` attribute of the `a` element: that is the plain `abc.php`. You can achieve this by adding the `onclick` attribute with `return false;`:

```
echo "<td>"."<a href='abc.php' onclick='return false;'>".$row['a']."</a></td>";
```

Comment: okay noted , will update when I try it it later. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

You tried to get an attribute a for the link.
If you need to get link text, use `$(this).text()`

```
var a = $(this).text();
alert(a);
```

You can pass text to the next page by get parameters, for example:

```
echo "<td>"."<a href='abc.php?text=".$row['a']."'>".$row['a']."</a></td>";
```

or on the client-side using `window.location.href=""`